# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Foo.Bar.Delegates.Program.ParseIntDelegate'

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to learn C# delegates.  I receive this error message in my subject line when compiling this bit of code.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Foo.Bar.Delegates.Program.ParseIntDelegate'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Foo.Bar.Delegates
{
    class Program
   {
        private delegate int ParseIntDelegate();

        private static int Parse(string x)
        {
            return int.Parse(x);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            string x = "40";
            int y = Parse(x); //The method I want to point the delegate to

            ParseIntDelegate firstParseIntMethod = Parse(x); 

           //generates complier error: cannot implicity convert type int 
           //to 'Foo.Bar.Delegates.Program.ParseIntDelegate'

           ParseIntDelegate secondParseIntMethod = int.Parse(x); //Same error

           Console.WriteLine("Integer is {0}", firstParseIntMethod()); 
        }
    }
}
```

So I am stuck until I can understand what it is I am doing wrong.  If someone could help me figure this out I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your delegate type should be:

```
private delegate int ParseIntDelegate(string str);
```

The delegate type should match the signature of the method you want to convert. In this case `Parse` takes a single `string` argument and returns an `int`.

Since your `Parse` method has a compatible signature, you can create a new delegate instance from it directly:

```
ParseIntDelegate firstParseIntMethod = Parse;
```

Then you can invoke it like a normal method application:

```
Console.WriteLine("Integer is {0}", firstParseIntMethod(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things that jump out at me:

In Main(), you have

```
ParseIntDelegate firstParseIntMethod = Parse(x);
```

This tries to store the result of Parse(x) into firstParseIntMethod. You're *invoking* Parse here, not referring to it.

You can fix this by removing the parameter:

```
ParseIntDelegate firstParseIntMethod = Parse ;
```

Now you'll have a different error, complaining about Parse's signature.

```
private delegate int ParseIntDelegate();

private static int Parse(string x)
```

Parse can't 'fit' into a ParseIntDelegate because it requires a string parameter. You can change the ParseIntDelegate to take a string to resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes, first refer, then invoke and get the signature matched.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Glad to help -- if this was useful to you, you might mark Lee's answer as solving your problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem where I had put () and the end of my assignment and could not see it until coming here.